# Where to define connection string as global in C# windows app(Like WebConfig in Web App)?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlconnection, windows

As my question I want to know where can i define a global connection string In Windows Forms Applications in C#? Just like Web-config in Web Applications. AND how to use/access that connection in my code behinds?
please respect my apology for this simple question.I'm new to windows form apps
Thank you very much

Comment: in `App.config` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will place your connection string inside `app.config` file.

[How to get connection string from app.config](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-Cs)

Comment: Thanks a lot,There it is.Very Well.
Be Lucky My Friend

Comment: now you can mark this post as answered @user3823980

Comment: Sure.i just was waiting to spent 11 minute to have permission to mark this.
thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use User's Setting option from the Project Properties. you can create properties here to store the connection info. and you can update it by creating a separate configuration window.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

there is complete tutorial on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17659/How-To-Use-the-Settings-Class-in-C) how to use this feature in your application and provide connection information at runtime.

Comment: This way is Answer, Thanks, But the Simplest Way was Zohaib Aslam's Answer(first answer)
Any Way.Thanks for your attention